# A basic question on functions and limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $f,g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be such that

(1) $f$ and $g$ are both continuous at $x=2$

(2) $f\left(2-\frac 1n\right)=g(2\cos(2\pi n))$ for all $n$ greater than or equal to $1$.

Prove or disprove $f(2)=g(2)$.

Answer (score 0):

Since both functions are continuous, ** The limit through any one path is equal to the actual limit of the function. ** (This is important)
Here, We choose the path of n ∈ N and n ->  ∞.
(Because that is easy to apply on the relation given between f and g)
Then, as n->  ∞ , (2n - 1)/n -> 2 and 2cos(2n pi ) is always 2.
So, through that path, we get f(2) = g(2).

Comment: But the problem is saying f(2-1/n)= f(2) is not valid in case of oscillatory functions like f(x)= Sin(1/(x-2)) for this case we'll define the functional value at x=2 to make this function continous but I'm not able to generate a concrete example yet.

Comment: $f(x)$ being continuous at $x=2$ means (either by a simple theorem or by the very definition, depending on what your definitions of continuous and limit of a function are) that $\forall \{x_n\} : \lim x_n = 2, \lim f(x_n) = f(2)$.

Comment: Sorry for the typing I'm not good in mathematical typing so, it may be hard to understand. I'm sorry for that